# How can call a web service in VS 2010?

Tags: asp.net

I have added a remote web service to my project using "add service reference" in Vs 2010 Express edition,
but I don't know how to call the web service, I only find some new files type such as .wsdl, .disco and I can't find .cs file

You can download the project at https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=793d6d4ebb70b0ef&resid=793D6D4EBB70B0EF!132

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do this:

```
using(ServiceReference1.ChinaStockWebServiceSoapClient service = new ServiceReference1.ChinaStockWebServiceSoapClient("ChinaStockWebServiceSoap"))
    {
      var result =  service.getStockInfoByCode("MSFT");
    }
```

Comment: To CjCoax;

Your code is Ok, thanks again!

but when I run the code below, I get error, why? but I can find ChinaStockWebServiceHttpGet in .wsdl file

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Could not find endpoint element with name 'ChinaStockWebServiceHttpGet' and contract 'ServiceReference1.ChinaStockWebServiceHttpGet'
 
<hr/>  <br/>
using (ServiceReference1.ChinaStockWebServiceHttpGetClient  service = new ServiceReference1.ChinaStockWebServiceHttpGetClient("ChinaStockWebServiceHttpGet"))

Answer (score 0):

If you've named your service reference "MyService", then you need to create an instance of "MyServiceClient":

```
using(MyServiceClient svc = new MyServiceClient())
{
  svc.WebServiceMethod(...); // this will vary according to the service definition
}
```